# Xcode doesn't show scheme selector

Tags: xcode6

I don't know why it disappeared and how to let it reappear... Currently I always have to go through "Edit Scheme", which is kind of annoying...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheme selection on the bar is dropped if the Xcode window is too narrow.  The far right of the bar shows >> to tell you that there is more to see if you widen the window